# The semantic meaning of owl:onClass

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I am very new to OWL/RDF, can someone elaborate the meaning of `owl:onClass`, sometimes it is used in restrictions instead of `owl:someValuesFrom` or `owl:allValuesFrom`

Comment: I'd assume the name itself makes the meaning clear? restriction of a property on a class, i.e. on it's values with which the property is used - note, this restriction isn't the same as a constraint but used for inference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [owl:onClass](http://i2web.eu/ns/2012/usermodel/owl_onClass.html)

*The property that determines the class that a qualified object cardinality restriction refers to.*

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification, I was confused by the way universal and existential restrictions are declared compared to qualified object cardinality restrictions. For universal and existential, owl:onProperty is declared together with owl:allvaluesFrom or owl:somevaluesFrom to show the class were relationships exists to form the restriction class of individuals. I thought it is the same for qualified cardinality restrictions but then i noticed they use owl:onClass to show which class the property relationship applies to while creating the anonymous restriction class.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link in this answer no longer works. I tried getting it from the Wayback machine, but it reports that this address was never crawled.